# what is the difference between magento 2.1.7 and 2.1.8?

Tags: magento-2.1.7, magento-2.1.8

I chose **magento 2.1.7** for a project. Now during the project my client asked me to upgrade it to **magento 2.1.8**. Can someone explain the difference?

Comment: here is the release note of magento 2.1.8. Please read it. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.8CE.html

Comment: As a note, Magento 2.1.8 is having some issues with longer reindexing times compared to previous versions. If you have a larger catalog it might be in your interest to delay this update until these issues are resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one better.

Magento 2.1.8 is a maintenance release, featuring over 100 bug fixes and improvements.

As Abhishek Panchal noted, you can view the full 2.1.8 release notes here with the list of bugs fixed: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.8CE.html

## Highlights

- multiple enhancements to static content deployment and generation
- improvements to indexing of large catalogs, cache tuning, and **URL
  re-writes
- reduction in the amount of memory that mass actions require, and
  performance optimization
- faster deployments for multi-language sites

Comment: You mean URL rewrite generate can be  achieve by Index management ? like Magento 1 @Ryan

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed 2 differences since upgrading from 2.1.7 to 2.1.8.

Navigation to subcategories in admin is now broken in Chrome and IE (thankfully still works in Firefox).

Also on the category page if you try to filter by manufacturer it always displays 0 results.

I wouldn't recommend upgrading personally.

Comment: category page filters behaving strange for me too. product count is happening only for in stock items.

Comment: Someone has posted a fix for filters on github that works for me if you're still having issues with it:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/2c62aa376eeed447e632aedb42085c9d255520df

I'm just upgrading to 2.1.9 and applying the fix again as Magento still haven't included it